# Unit testing a Rust fallible function extensively

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust, automated-tests

Given this fallible function written in Rust:

```rust
pub fn fallible(source_file: &str) -> Result<bool> {
    trace!("Opening file {}", source_file);
    let file = File::open(source_file).map_err(|e| {
        error!("{e}");
        let msg = format!("Failed to open {source_file}");
        anyhow::Error::msg(msg)
    })?;

    let reader = BufReader::new(&file);

    let mut matched = false;
    let line_fallback = String::from("");

    for (_idx, line) in reader.lines().enumerate() {
        let line = line.as_ref().unwrap_or_else(|e| {
            // UNTESTED LINES
            error!("{e}");
            &line_fallback
        });

        if line.to_lowercase().contains("query") == true {
            matched = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if matched == false {
        trace!("Found no query reference");
    }

    Ok(matched)
}
```

and the associate unit test:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn true_if_reference_is_found() {
        let ret = fallible("mocks/reference.txt");
        assert_eq!(ret.unwrap(), true);
    }

    #[test]
    fn false_if_reference_is_not_found() {
        let ret = fallible("mocks/no-reference.txt");
        assert_eq!(ret.unwrap(), false);
    }

    #[test]
    fn error_if_file_does_not_exist() {
        let ret = fallible("./not-existant-file.txt");
        assert_eq!(ret.is_err(), true);
    }
}
```

Sadly the following function lines remain untested:

```rust
let line = line.as_ref().unwrap_or_else(|e| {
    // UNTESTED LINES
    error!("{e}");
    &line_fallback
});
```

How I'm supposed to test those as well?
Is the [fail-rs](https://github.com/tikv/fail-rs) crate a viable option?

Comment: Please do not put the line numbers in the code.

Comment: Sorry, I just removed them and reworded the question

Answer (score 2):

As always in these cases, inject your dependendencies. Instead of accepting a path to your source file, accept an object implementing `Reader`. This allows you to use a mock reader object in your tests that returns an error for some line. If you want to, you can still provide a convenience wrapper that accepts a path. (As a side note, the "right" way to accept a path is using the type `impl AsRef<Path>`, not `&str`.)

That said, that I have doubts that you actually *need* to test these lines. Rust needs far less test coverage than highly dynamic languages like Python, Ruby or JavaScript, and also less test coverage than many statically typed languages like Java or Go, since the compiler and the type system are much stricter. Even for dynamic languages, 100% test coverage is a [highly](https://neverworkintheory.org/2021/09/24/coverage-is-not-strongly-correlated-with-test-suite-effectiveness.html) [questionable](https://preslav.me/2020/12/03/the-myth-of-code-coverage/) [goal](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=20050090). For Rust, it is almost certainly a waste of time that makes your life miserable while buying you nothing.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, hints and advises. This is a small learning project, thus I'd like drill down deep on various aspects. I agree with you on the 100% coverage as a highly questionable goal, especially if we are talking about line coverage. Without getting mad, I'm more interested in branch coverage and cyclomatic complexity.

Comment: I don't think there is a "right way" to accepting anything.  Yes, an explicit type exists to represent arbitrary paths, and the community follows an `AsRef<Path>` pattern since it's implemented for many types, including `&str`, but I'm not going to go as far as "right way".

Comment: @LucaAnceschi As the answer suggests, using generics and bounding on behavior will give you the most flexibility here.  It increases your compile times in general, but you gain the characteristic in tests that you want.